# Exercise 13, Section 17 of Munkres’ Topology And Using This Result to Prove $\{x|f(x)=g(x)\}$ is Closed in $X$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> Show that $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta =\{ x\times x|x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times X$.

**My attempt:** first suppose $X$ is Hausdorff. let $(X\times X)-\Delta=\{ m\times n\in X\times X| m\neq n\}$. Let $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$, $\exists U_x, U_y\in \mathcal{T}_{X}$ such that $U_x\cap U_y=\phi$, by Hausdorff property of $X$. $\mathcal{B}=\{ U\times V|U,V\in \mathcal{T}_X\}$ is basis for $\mathcal{T}_p$, product topology. We want to show $(X\times X)-\Delta \in \mathcal{T}_p$. Claim: $(X\times X)-\Delta= \bigcup_{x\times y\in (X\times X)-\Delta} (U_x \times U_y)$. For $x\times y\in (X\times X)-\Delta, \exists U_x \times U_y\in \mathcal{B}$(existence depends on Hausdorff property) such that $x\times y\in U_x \times U_y \subseteq \bigcup_{x\times y\in (X\times X)-\Delta} (U_x \times U_y)$. Thus $(X\times X)-\Delta \subseteq \bigcup_{x\times y\in (X\times X)-\Delta} (U_x \times U_y)$. Now let $p\times q\in \bigcup_{x\times y\in (X\times X)-\Delta} (U_x \times U_y)$. Then $p\times q\in U_x \times U_y$, for some $x\times y\in (X\times X)-\Delta$. Since $U_x \cap U_y=\phi$ i.e. $\nexists z\in X$ such that $z\in U_x \cap U_y$. So $U_x \times U_y=\{ r\times s|r\in U_x, s \in U_y\}\subseteq (X\times X)-\Delta$, since $r\neq s$ (by $U_x \cap U_y=\phi$). Thus $(X\times X)-\Delta \supseteq \bigcup_{x\times y\in (X\times X)-\Delta} (U_x \times U_y)$. Hence $\Delta$ is closed in $X\times X$.

Conversely, suppose $\Delta$ is closed in $X\times X$. So $(X\times X)-\Delta=\{m\times n\in X\times X|m\neq n\} \in \mathcal{T}_p$. $(X\times X)-\Delta=\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times V_i)$, where $(U_i\times V_i) \in \mathcal{B}$. Let $x\times y\in (X\times X)-\Delta$. Then $x\times y\in U_j \times V_j$, for some $j\in I$.  Claim: $U_j\cap V_j=\phi$. Assume towards contradiction i.e. $U_j \cap V_j \neq \phi$. That means $\exists p\in U_j \cap V_j$. $p\in U_j$ and $p\in V_j$. So $p\times p\in U_j \times V_j$. Which implies $p\times p\in \bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times V_i)$. Thus $p\times p\in (X\times X)-\Delta$. Which contradicts the definition of $(X\times X)-\Delta$. Our initial assumption is wrong. Hence $U_j\cap V_j =\phi$.

---

> lemma: Let $f, g : X \to Y$ be continuous; assume $Y$ is Hausdorff. Show that $\{x \mid f(x) = g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

You may have thought(I did) to prove this lemma by somehow showing inverse image of a closed set of continuous map is precisely $\{x|f(x)=g(x)\}$ set, hence closed in $X$. But constructing that map is not obvious/natural, at first glance(at least in my case). So later, I drop this strategy to prove above property of Hausdorff space. In my opinion, this is a candidate approach, one should consider.

**Proof:** https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3177710/861687

Comment: You proof is correct, (expect that you wrote claim: $U_j\times V_j=\phi$ where it should be $U_j\cap V_j=\phi$.

Comment: @ArcticChar How do you find such old post? Search engine didn’t recommend that post even once! I wouldn’t have written an answer if I knew that post exists.

Comment: I just use google to search "X is Hausdorff if the diagonal is closed".

Comment: @ArcticChar ohhh... google recommended. I use title(search engine) in question section to see related post.

Comment: @usee264745 there is a website created by a MSE user(whose username I forgot) approach0.xyz which very accurately searches posts on MSE and AoPS using some/all keywords of your question/solution(I recommend using the raw query tab as the automatic formula bar used to have some issues some time ago(althought it might have been fixed now)).

Comment: The search engine in stackexchange is weaker in general.

Comment: Related meta post on approach0 [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange)

Comment: @user600016 can you please give link of that website?

Comment: @ArcticChar it took me long time to write all the things down. It got closed less than the time I spent writing this post.

Comment: @user264745 As I mentioned it's approach0.xyz  For your question, https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24X%20%5Ctimes%20X%24%2C%20OR%20content%3AHausdorff%2C%20OR%20content%3Adiagonal&p=1 generates several results on same/similar topics.

Comment: @user600016 thank you. At least I got to know something new.

Comment: @user264745 Don't feel disheartened. People here are always glad to help. It just saves your time and the time of others by marking a post duplicate (and thereby closing it). In case you are unable to understand the answers of all the duplicate posts, edit your question accordingly as to why you aren't able to and there is a high chance that your post will get reopened/someone helps you out in the comment section.

Comment: Now I check your profile and it seems that you are going through Munker's book. Note that his book is (1) elementary and (2) very, very popular, hence it is very likely that most of the exercise had been asked on MSE already. Googling first (and approach0) would definitely save some of your future time.

Comment: Thank you @user600016

Comment: Thank you @ArcticChar . Yeah that is so true.

Comment: Given that the diagonal is closed in $X \times X$, it's inverse image under the (almost obvious) continuous function $x\mapsto (f(x), g(x))\colon X \rightarrow X \times X$ is closed in $X$, and equal to $\{x\in X\,|\,f(x) = g(x)\}$.