# Exercise 13, Section 18 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $A \subset X$; let $f \colon A \to Y$ be continuous; let $Y$ be Hausdorff. Show that if $f$ may be extended to a continuous function $g \colon \overline{A} \to Y$, then $g$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

**My attempt:** let $g_1:\overline{A}\to Y$ and $g_2:\overline{A}\to Y$ are continuous maps, and $g_1|_A=g_2|_A=f$. Clearly $A\subseteq \{x\in \overline{A}| g_1(x)=g_2(x)\}=G\subseteq \overline{A}$. By [Exercise 13, Section 17 of Munkres’ Topology And Using This Result to Prove $\{x|f(x)=g(x)\}$ is Closed in $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4357610/861687) result, $G$ is closed in $\overline{A}$. So $\overline{A}\subseteq G$. Thus $\overline{A}=\{ x\in \overline{A}|g_1(x)=g_2(x)\}$. In other word, $g_1(x)=g_2(x),\forall x\in \overline{A}$. Hence $g_1=g_2$. **Is this proof correct?**

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Just a small detail. Although it is indeed correct that $\overline A\subseteq G$, since $G$ is, by definition, a subset of $\overline A$, it would be more natural to simply write that $G=\overline A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is natural to use nets to show that $g_1 = g_2$ on $\overline{A}$. Let $x \in \overline{A}$ be arbitrary. Since $x \in \overline{A}$, there is a net $(x_{a})_{a \in A}$ in $A$ converging to $x$. Since $g_1$ and $g_2$ are continuous on $\overline{A}$, it follows that $g_1(x_a) \to g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x_a) \to g_2(x)$. Since limits of nets in a Hausdorff space are unique, it follows that $g_1(x) = g_2(x)$.

Comment: I known this approach in metric space. I haven’t prove $x\in \overline{A} \Rightarrow$ there is a net $(x_a)_{a\in A}$ and you used limit of sequence of continuity, which I know exist in metric space but I don’t about topological space.

Comment: @user264745 I didn't use sequences anywhere. Nets are an adaptation of sequences that allow metric space sequence arguments to work in an arbitrary topological space. One such result that adapts is that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for every net $x_a \to x$ we have $f(x_a) \to f(x)$.

Comment: I accepted your answer because this is the third way to solve exercise $18.13$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct as written.

To see that the hypothesis is necessary, let $Y=[0,1]\cup \{1'\}$ be the interval with double endpoint. Then $Y$ is a compact $T_1$ space (and a manifold) and for $X=[0,1]$ and $A=[0,1)$, you have two distinct continuous extensions of $f\colon A\to Y$ given by $f(x)=x$.

(I believe that with a bit more work, you can show that this property actually characterises Hausdorff spaces.)

Comment: What is $\{1^\prime \}$?

Comment: The singleton of a copy of $1$.